# Can you use HTML 5 with ASP.NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

Can you use HTML 5 with ASP.NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010?

The reason that I asked this is for a project I'm about to work upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  But you need to install SP1 and the Web Standards Update

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

Answer (score 0):

Yes: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/01/27/html5-amp-css3-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Integrate HTML5 into Existing ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC Applications
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj129609.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can download this extensions to support html 5 intellisense for visual studio 2010

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83?SRC=VSIDE